# Relativity and kinetic time dilation

Tags: special-relativity

**Background information**

---

I was learning about kinetic time dilation and I came up with a question that has me stumped for quite a while. Here it goes (it is a story-based problem, so some stuff here and there will be a little outlandish).

I am sorry if it is quite a elementary question, but I am quite new to relativity so I would appreciate if the answers would be thorough. Thank you!

If you want to see how gamma is derived, see this link: [Fermilab's derivation](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=qXxtqK7G4Uw&pp=ygUNTG9yZW50eiBnYW1tYQ%3D%3D)

---

### Two brothers

Imagine there are two brothers, Bob and Buck. They are standing on the north pole and both of them decide to challenge each other to a race. They shall measure the amount of time it will take to go one full revolution around Earth and back to the north pole.

First, Bob goes first. Bob has a finite but quite high speed and comes back after some days.

However, Buck has a superpower: he can travel at the speed of light!

Buck starts to run and comes back in no time.

---

The problem arises when I try to figure out what Bob will say to Buck. I am thinking of two possibilities:

1. "Why did you not run?". Buck, to his surprise, says "I ran Bob!!!"
2. "You ran but I could not measure the amount of time because you were so fast!"

My question is, will Bob see Buck run and come back in no time, or will Buck just stand still relative to Bob, but Buck actually did run the whole revolution?

I know that is will be "no time" because of the Lorentz gamma in special relativity.

\begin{align}
\frac{\Delta t'}{\Delta t} = \frac{2W/\sqrt{c^2 - v^2}}{2W/c} = \frac{c}{\sqrt{c^2 - v^2}} = \frac{1}{\sqrt{1 - v^2/c^2}} = \gamma
\end{align} (1)

where $Δt'$ is the time for the observer at rest and $Δt$ is the time for an observer in motion.

and because of this equation:

$$Δt′=γΔt$$ (2)

we know that an observer in motion relative to the observer at rest has time ticking more slow than the person at rest.

If v approaches c (limits), then we say that gamma will approach infinity. If we think intuitively what that means for equation (2), this means that the time for the person in motion relative to the stationary observer has **stopped**.

What I am confused about is, if Bob (the stationary observer) is measuring Buck's time (moving observer), will Bob see Buck frozen in time (then he cant measure the time because Buck has not moved relative to Bob), or will Bob see Buck moving at the speed of light but he cant measure the time because it is just impossible to do so?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It doesn't really make sense to talk about a frame of reference moving *at* the speed of light, because the time and space axes merge and the zeroes often make no mathematical sense. But we can talk about the limit as one approaches the speed of light arbitrarily closely.

What would happen is that Bob would see Buck move at the speed of light, taking a non-zero amount of time to get there, but he would observe that Buck's clock would slow to a stop. Bob would see Buck apparently 'frozen' as he moved. (That is, he would be 'frozen' like a statue, but 'moving' like a statue travelling at the speed of light.)

Buck would see the length of the course shrink to zero because of relativity (length contraction), so the start and end point were virtually identical, and it would therefore take no time at all to get from start to finish.

So, in fact it would be Bob who insisted that Buck had moved (at the speed of light, around the Earth), and Buck who would insist that he had not (because the circumference of the Earth would have shrunk to zero, and therefore there was no distance to travel).

Special relativity predicts two effects that are inter-related: time dilation - moving clocks run slow; and length contraction - moving objects shrink along the direction of motion. Both do so by the factor $\gamma$. They are really the same effect seen from different viewpoints. Buck sees Bob's stationary universe length-contracted by a factor $\gamma$. Bob sees Buck's clock slowed by a factor $\gamma$. The two effects conspire to keep observations consistent. Buck's clock reads zero, but Buck says that's due to length contraction, while Bob says it's due to time dilation. Bob's clock reads non-zero. Buck's explanation for that (how did Bob's clock *jump* during the zero time it took Buck to travel the zero distance?!) is rather trickier to explain.

--

It's a hard enough question that I'd advise a beginner in relativity to wait until they know more of the theory before trying to tackle it. However, for the sake of completeness, I'll try to give a *very* brief outline.

There are two ways to approach that more subtle question. One is to say that this race is a bit like the situation in the Twin Paradox, where Buck travels to the other side of the world and back again, ending up younger than his twin brother Bob. The shift occurs when Buck changes direction - instead of moving away he is moving towards - and this swings Buck's 'now' through spacetime.

The other way is based on the Ehrenfest Rotating Disc Paradox, in which the circumference of a disc rotating at almost the speed of light shrinks towards zero, but the radius of the disc stays the same. It turns out that in a rotating reference frame, time doesn't "join up" when you move around the disc, but instead "now" forms a helix in spacetime. Jumping from one loop of the helix to the next 'jumps' the time.

In the spacetime diagram below, time goes up the page. The time and space axes at each point on the rotating disc are tilted. If we join up the space and time axes of neighbouring points into smooth curves, they spiral around in spacetime, so that all the periodic cycles are in a sense the *same* instant of time in the rotating frame. (It might be called a 'surface of simultaneity' for the rotating frame.) As the helix gets steeper, the length along a loop shrinks to zero, but the vertical distance *between* the loops remains non-zero.

[image: Rotating frame twists time and space into a helix]

That's probably not a very clear explanation, but it's a difficult concept to explain in simple terms!

Comment: Hi @Nullius in Verba! I was wondering how Bob would argue with Buck that Buck moved if Bob saw Buck frozen as he moved?

Comment: I agree with the length contraction though

Comment: I agree, now you mention it, it does look a bit odd! Hopefully you knew what I meant, though?

Comment: I mean, A little bit... But it just does not wrap around my head much. Could you maybe explain that part a little bit more? Thank you!

Comment: "So, in fact it would be Bob who insisted that Buck had moved" this part is a little confusing.

Comment: Is that better?

Comment: So you are saying that the statue is moving along the speed of light? What does it mean that "time has stopped" for Buck relative to Bob. Would Bob not see Buck just standing still and time too? Or is it because it is "time stopped" and not "space time stopped"?

Comment: That's right. And you're welcome!

Comment: sorry for the edit in between

Comment: Thank you for taking the time to answer my doubts Nullius in Verba!

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/148437/discussion-between-shaun-kant-and-nullius-in-verba).